# .NET Framework execution was aborted. Another query caused the AppDomain db.dbo[runtime].4 to be unloaded

Tags: sql-server, sqlclr, clrstoredprocedure

I have a SQL CLR Function (written in c#.net) that I'm trying to debug. I attach visual studio to the sqlserver process and begin stepping through, but it keeps crashing and ending with the following error message:

---

.NET Framework execution was aborted. Another query caused the AppDomain DatabaseName.dbo[runtime].4 to be unloaded.

---

(The number after DatabaseName.dbo[runtime] changes - increments on each crash)

It sometimes even crashes the sql server process & stops the service.

The function works absolutely fine with no errors when I'm not debugging. This only happens when I'm debugging.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: Also it's SQL Server 2008 and Visual Studo 2008 I'm working with.

Comment: Could it be a different process calling your CLR SP? SQL might have to terminate your debugging process to run the SP again.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same message today - for me, the reason was the change in the 'max server memory' configuration while the SSIS load was running.

What might have helped here is an extract from the SQL Server Log:

[image: SQL Server Error Log]